# Issues with String Replace in C# with double curly/square parenthesis

Tags: c#, string, replace

I'm trying to find a way to replace predefined "tags" in a text with alternative text using c#, but I'm having difficulties finding a simple way to use string.replace or a suitable regex solution that works.

Use case:

Replace all instances of {{xxxxxx}} in a given text with something different, like "yyyyy yyyyyy"

If {{xxxxx}} is problematic in itself, I can change to either [[xxxxxx]] or ((xxxxxx)).

At the moment, I cannot find a single String or Regex operation that will work with any of the above patterns.

Comment: Have you tried `string.Replace`? Show your code and explain what goes wrong.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("hey {{aaa}} bye ".Replace("{{aaa}}", "hello hello")); ` Could you please elaborate why string replace doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

This is an `Regex` example of how to easily achieve tag replacement

```
\{\{(.*?)}}
```

**Code**

```
var someText = "blah blah blah {{Hello}} blah";
var substitute = "Rah";
var result = Regex.Replace(someText, @"\{\{(.*?)}}", substitute);
```

**Output**

```
blah blah blah Rah blah
```

**Explination**

- { matches the character { literally (case sensitive)
- { matches the character { literally (case sensitive)

  - **1st Capturing Group (.*?)**

    - .*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
    - *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- }} matches the characters }} literally (case sensitive)

  - **Global pattern flags**

    - g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)

Answer (score 0):

In some contexts (like some overloads of Console.WriteLine) curly braces in a string may be interpreted as starting and ending a [format item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting). However, the example code you provided [works for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZxPQP0).